# What does it mean to clone() an object?

Tags: clone

What is object cloning in vb6 or java? In what situation do we use a clone? What does cloning objects mean? Can any one tell me with example please.

Comment: Seems obvious to experienced people, but beginners often struggle with "hey, why'd my object change when I changed this 'other' one".  The realization that names are basically gussied up pointers comes slowly (and understanding cloning greatly speeds that process).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cloning is actually copying the object data into a new object.

This example doesn't clone the data:

```
Foo p = new Foo();
Foo o = p;
```

If `Foo` has a member `a` and you change `p.a` then `o.a` also changes because both `p` and `o` point to the same object.

However,

```
Foo p = new Foo();
Foo o = p.Clone();
```

In this case if you change `p.a` then `o.a` remains the same because they actually point to separate objects.

There are actually two different ways you can clone: shallow clone or deep clone.

A shallow clone just makes a new object and copies the members into the new object.  This means that if one of the members is actually a pointer to another object then that object will be shared between the old object and new object.

A deep clone actually goes through and clones all the members into the new object.  That way the objects are complete copies of all the data.

Comment: BTW, there's a third way of cloning--a semantic-level clone.  A semantic-level clone of e.g. a List<T> would be a new list containing the same items as the old one.

Comment: @supercat - how is that different than a shallow clone of the list?

Comment: @Aaron: Suppose a collection is implemented as a reference to an array along with a count of how many items are valid.  A shallow clone of an object holding such a collection would be a new object with a copied valid-items count but a reference to the same array of items as the original.  A sematic-level clone would have a copied count and a reference to shallow clone of the array.

Comment: @Aaron: A good way to make a semantic-level clone of an object is to start with a shallow clone and then clone all the fields the object "knows" about.  Objects should generally not expose shallow-cloning functionality, but only use it internally.

Comment: @supercat - I see - A semantic-level clone is like a shallow clone that knows about the internals of complex objects.  Good to know.

Comment: @Aaron: It's a useful concept which I haven't seen discussed much.  In many cases, it's the most logical behavior for a "Clone" method.

Answer (score 2):

Generaly speaking objects are passed by reference.  So if you say `$objB=$objA` you are not getting a new object; you are getting a new name for the same object.  However, if you say `$objB= clone $objA` you get a copy of `$objA`.  In the first case, whatever you do to `$objB` also happens to `$objA`.  In the 2nd case, `$objB` is independent.