# clone object in c#

Tags: c#, .net

What is clone object and types?can give simple example ?and is possible call clone object to List ?

Comment: It's something you should avoid.

Comment: @Henk - why should it be avoided? Its quite practical in some instances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does it mean to clone() an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749581/what-does-it-mean-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy constructor versus Clone()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345389/copy-constructor-versus-clone)

Comment: There are hundreds of questions regarding cloning in .NET. Did you take the time to look at the questions that suggested the question may already have been asked?

Answer (score 3):

Look here: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/cloning-objects-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

A clone is a copy (i.e. a new instance). Several BCL classes implement `IClonable` which returns an `object` which should be a new instance with the values of the original.

A good sample is at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx

I don't think `List<T>` supports it, but you could add it, as long as the `T` are `IClonable`.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning means creating another instance of your Reference type (Anything that is not a constant [integers, chars...] or a structure) so you can modify one of them without affecting the other, as just using the Equals operator or passing one of such value types would create a pseudo-pointer.

To clone your classes, just make them implement ICloneable [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx] and call the Clone() Method, casting the return type to the object type desired.

Good Luck :)